# Get ruff / ruff_lsp to work with neovim

Tags: neovim, lua, lsp, python

I tried [kickstart.nvimi](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim) to get to work with the [ruff-lsp](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-lsp). It did not work, therefore I built a minimal example with only the default configuration from the documentation.

Here is the problem: When I try to jump to the definition of a variable (usually bound to the keys `<leader>sd`, I get the error:

```
method textDocument/references is not supported by any of the servers registered for the current buffer
```

Other LSP functions don't work either.
The only usable thing is, that a `import not used` warning.
`LspInfo` shows no problem.

```
Detected filetype:   python

1 client(s) attached to this buffer:

Client: ruff_lsp (id: 1, bufnr: [1])
 filetypes:       python
 autostart:       true
 root directory:  /home/konrad/airfetch
 cmd:             /home/konrad/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/airfetch-GoHfdGeT-py3.10/bin/ruff-lsp

Configured servers list: ruff_lsp
```

Here is the *fairly* minimal `init.lua`. I tried this with no other plugins set.

```lua
vim.g.mapleader = ' '
vim.g.maplocalleader = ' '

local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath 'data' .. '/lazy/lazy.nvim'
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system {
    'git',
    'clone',
    '--filter=blob:none',
    'https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git',
    '--branch=stable', -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  }
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

require('lazy').setup({
    'neovim/nvim-lspconfig',
    'astral-sh/ruff-lsp'
    })

-- See: https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/tree/54eb2a070a4f389b1be0f98070f81d23e2b1a715#suggested-configuration
local opts = { noremap=true, silent=true }
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>e', vim.diagnostic.open_float, opts)
vim.keymap.set('n', '[d', vim.diagnostic.goto_prev, opts)
vim.keymap.set('n', ']d', vim.diagnostic.goto_next, opts)
vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>q', vim.diagnostic.setloclist, opts)

-- Use an on_attach function to only map the following keys
-- after the language server attaches to the current buffer
local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  -- Enable completion triggered by <c-x><c-o>
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, 'omnifunc', 'v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc')

  -- Mappings.
  -- See `:help vim.lsp.*` for documentation on any of the below functions
 local bufopts = { noremap=true, silent=true, buffer=bufnr }
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gD', vim.lsp.buf.declaration, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gi', vim.lsp.buf.implementation, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-k>', vim.lsp.buf.signature_help, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>wa', vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>wr', vim.lsp.buf.remove_workspace_folder, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>wl', function()
    print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()))
  end, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>D', vim.lsp.buf.type_definition, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>rn', vim.lsp.buf.rename, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>ca', vim.lsp.buf.code_action, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gr', vim.lsp.buf.references, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>f', function() vim.lsp.buf.format { async = true } end, bufopts)
end

-- Configure `ruff-lsp`.
-- See: https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#ruff_lsp
-- For the default config, along with instructions on how to customize the settings
require('lspconfig').ruff_lsp.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  init_options = {
    settings = {
      -- Any extra CLI arguments for `ruff` go here.
      args = {},
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Ruff is a Python linter that only analyzes imports. The Ruff LSP exposes an LSP interface for that linter, but cannot equip it with features it does not have. See for example the README, which specifically lists "fixing" import-related issues and nothing else.

If you need other LSP features for Python, you'll need a different LSP (though I imagine you could have both running as long as something could mediate the results from both).

Comment: OK, strange. The keybindings for "<leader>sd" are copied from the ruff website, see https://pypi.org/project/ruff/0.0.240/#editor-integrations.

Comment: @Dronakuul that looks like boilerplate config for LSPs.